# npm command-line interface to inject version number into file

Tags: npm, build, version

Is there any CLI I can use with an `npm` script to inject my `package.json` version into some arbitrary file? I don't want to use gulp or grunt or webpack, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in three parts.

It turns out the NPM puts the package version in an environment variable named `npm_package_version` when running [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

There is an NPM package called [`replace-in-file`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) that provides a CLI for replacing strings.

Unfortunately the format for environment variable replacement on Windows (e.g. `%FOO_BAR%`) isn't the same as on Linux (e.g. `$FOO_BAR`). Luckily there is another NPM package called [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) that makes environment variables consistent across platforms.

Put them together and you can replace e.g. `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT` with the current package version in all `.example` files in the `dist` directory using the following script in `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
  "build:insert-version": "cross-var replace-in-file \"x.x.x-SNAPSHOT\" \"$npm_package_version\" \"dist/*.example\""
}
```