# Angular Library: Display Current Version

Tags: angular

Good day,

I have a standalone angular library with a component. I would like to display the current version from the library's package.json file in the component.

I have tried adding `"resolveJsonModule": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to the `tsconfig.lib.json` file and importing `package.json` in the component, but I get the error:

**"'lib-name/'package.json' is not under 'rootDir' 'lib-name/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files."**

Does anyone know how else I can get this done in Angular 12?

Comment: You want to show current angular library version in library component file?

Comment: Not the angular version. The version of my own library, I want to show that in the component file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure about the answer to your question. Could you share the code how you importing package.json in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm command-line interface to inject version number into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238358/npm-command-line-interface-to-inject-version-number-into-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

In my `lib-name/src` folder, I have a `config.ts` file. In that file, I added the following code:

```
const packageJson = require('../package.json');
export const LIB_VERSION = packageJson.version;
```

This code imports the `package.json` file and assigns its contents to the `packageJson` variable. Then, it exports a constant called `LIB_VERSION` that contains the value of the version property from the `packageJson` object.

Then I use `LIB_VERSION` constant anywhere I need to within the library. For example, this is how I use it in the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LIB_VERSION } from '../config';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-name',
  template: `
    <h1>Library v{{version}}</h1>
  `
})
export class MyLibraryComponent {
  version = LIB_VERSION;
}
```